# 'npm' não é reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes

Tags: laravel, node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

Boa noite! Estou com esse problema. Já tentei algumas coisas que achei na net mas nada funcionou até agora. O npm está instalado (npm@6.7.0 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm) e o PATH também (C:\Program Files\nodejs). Me ajudem por favor:

```
$ npm run dev

> @ dev C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp
> npm run development

'npm' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Segue abaixo o log de erro:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'dev' ]
2 info using npm@6.7.0
3 info using node@v11.10.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle @~predev: @
6 info lifecycle @~dev: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~dev: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Jeferson\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapat;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQ";C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapat;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin;.;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Users\Jeferson\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Jeferson\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\Jeferson\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs
9 verbose lifecycle @~dev: CWD: C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp
10 silly lifecycle @~dev: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run development' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: @ dev: `npm run development`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:197:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:197:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:984:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:265:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v11.10.0
19 verbose npm  v6.7.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ dev: `npm run development`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Você instalou o NPM? Se sim, certificou-se de adicionar ao PATH do Windows?

Comment: oque vc está fazendo, digitando npm no terminal?

Comment: Olá! Alterei o post com as informações. Obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: O erro em questão está meio incoeso, já que primeiramente é dito que `npm` não é reconhecido como comando, mas depois mostra alguns _logs_ de erro do NPM.  Tem certeza que aquela é a mensagem correta do erro que você recebe?

Comment: Concordo com você que é estranho, mas este é o retorno que tenho. Se digito apenas 'npm' ele me mostra as opções. Se digito 'npm -v' ele me dá o retorno '6.7.0'. Se digito 'npm run' ele me mostra as opções, mas, por fim, se digito 'npm run dev' ele me retorna o erro acima. Vou editar a pergunta e adicionar o log de erro para ver se ajuda. Grato pela atenção!

Comment: Eu acho que você está chamando `nmp` do `bash` ou do `powershell`. Chama do prompt do `DOS` ou então entre(tanto no bash quanto o powershell) com o comando `CMD.exe` que abre um prompt do DOS, faça seu trabalho com `nmp` e use `exit` para sair do `DOS`.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Muito grato! Dessa forma funciona!!! Só não entendi ainda porque no bash do VS Code não funciona :(... Mas pelo menos agora consigo continuar os estudos! Valeu!

Comment: @JefersonFerreira. Porque tanto o bash como o `powershell` não dão suporte convencional as variáveis de ambiente. O `powershell` só dá suporte, a essas variáveis via active directory e bash por sua vez usa a dinâmica `POSIX` que ignora as variáveis de ambiente. Então quando você chama o `cmd.exe` você está na verdade invocando o ambiente DOS que fornece alguns protocolos de sistema dentre os quais estão incluídos essas variáveis necessárias a execução do `nmp`.

Comment: Entendi. Valeu pela ajuda! Abraço!

Answer (score 3):

Para resolver o problema, execute no *terminal*:

```
npm install --global cross-env
```

Execute novamente o `npm run dev`

> Fonte: [schoolofnet](https://www.schoolofnet.com/forum/topico/npm-run-dev-ao-rodar-sempre-da-erro-segue-log-abaixo-baixei-direto-do-github-rodei-o-npm-install-2282)
>
> Outra fonte: [SoEn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43387209/laravel-5-4-npm-run-dev-error/46993512#46993512)

Comment: Ele está em ambiente Windows. Não existe `sudo` para windows.

Comment: Pronto, alterei!

Comment: Até existe `sudo` para o Windows. Mas é bem rudimentar e só funciona se você instalar suporte para `POSIX` só server para adicionar algumas ferramentas do core linux no windows.

Comment: Infelizmente não deu certo aqui :(

Comment: Qual erro apareceu quando executou esse comando?

Comment: https://npm.community/t/problem-installing-depcheck-with-npm-6-7-0/4913/3 aqui fala sobre  essa versao apresentar alguns bugs

Comment: Quando rodo o `install` ele dá update de 1 pacote. Depois rodando o `dev` dá o mesmo erro.

Comment: Que estranho, tenta usar essas 2 versōes, da um downgrade no `Node: 10.14.1` e
 `npm: 6.8.0`

Comment: Não funcionou também. Só funciona no `cmd` do Windows (dica do @AugustoVasques).

Comment: Vou colocar em formato de resposta pois eu vi no Meta uma publicação alertando sobre [não colocar respostas nos comentários](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7663/respostas-em-coment%C3%A1rios).