# '.' não é reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes. alguém pode me ajudar please?

Tags: visual-studio-code, puppeteer

> projeto-pupeeteer@1.0.0 test
> ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --timeout=30000 ./tests

'.' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

Comment: Erro similar nessa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/365409/npm-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-reconhecido-como-um-comando-interno-ou-externo-um-programa-oper%C3%A1vel). Essa linha está aonde no seu código? Dê mais detalhes.

Comment: O erro aparece logo depois de eu digitar npm run test                                                                          

 ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --timeout=30000 ./tests
'.' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Neste caso no Puppeteer é preciso inserir a palavra 'node' antes do restante deste script.

Substitua isto:

"test": "./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --timeout=30000 ./tests"

Por isto:

"test": " node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --timeout=30000 ./tests"